# Searching through multiple files does not work

Tags: java, file, search

Ok, so i have this function, which i use to search for specific text in a file, when it finds that text in the file, it should return all the lines in all the files which contain that text
So, i have a function which does that...but i have another function a little bit different, which does not return anything, and i am very sure the file contains the searched text...
so, here is the function that does work:

```
    public void searchText(String text, CommandSender p) {

    File[] searchFiles = new File[files.size()];
    searchFiles = files.toArray(searchFiles);

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    for(File searchFile : searchFiles)
    {
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(searchFile);
            br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.indexOf(text) >= 0) {
                    p.sendMessage(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if((fileReader != null) && (br != null))
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                    fileReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if((fileReader != null) && (br != null))
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                    fileReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That function nicely gives these lines to the console.
But when i use this function:

```
    public String searchPos(int x, int y, int z) {
    String xyz = z + ", " + y + ", " + z;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    File[] searchFiles = new File[files.size()];
    searchFiles = files.toArray(searchFiles);

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    for(File searchFile : searchFiles)
    {
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(searchFile);
            br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if ((line.indexOf(xyz) >= 0) || (line.contains(xyz))) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if((fileReader != null) && (br != null))
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                    fileReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if((fileReader != null) && (br != null))
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                    fileReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return  sb.toString();
}
```

The return is just "" or nothing, and i just can't understand why the first function does work, and the second doesn't.

Thanks in advance, blackwolf12333

Answer (score 0):

You never add anything to the `StringBuffer` object, so I would expect it to return `""`

Comment: i do add things, but the answer that was below was correct...so thanks, whoever answered it...:P Sorry for bothering you guys with this